# RegExp filter in JavaScript (Angular.js)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to custom filter in `Angular.js`.

In case an object has `name == null`, and I insert "u" to `filter->` it returns `obj`, which `name == null` because `re.test(null)=true`, but others characters are returning `false`.  Can you tell me why? How can I prevent this case?

Comment: This is url  to custom filter : http://jsfiddle.net/fredrik/26fZb/1/

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if `obj.name` is also defined before testing it with regexp:

```
$scope.searchFilter = function(obj) {
  var re = new RegExp($scope.searchText, 'i');
  return !$scope.searchText || (obj.name && re.test(obj.name)) || re.test(obj.age.toString());
};
```

Otherwise, `null` casted to String type yields `"null"` and it's matched of course.

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/26fZb/232/